# Cocos2d-x - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, ios6, xcode4.5, cocos2d-x

I am getting these messages in Cocos2d-x (2.1.5) when doing a tutorial (Air Hockey) from the book "Cocos2d-x Beginner Guide".

I have checked all the "#include", BuildPhases etc. in Xcode as well as performed "Validate Settings" in "Compile Sources" (approx. 250 files) and screened internet and would appreciate anyones view on this. I have not yet referred to them in the .cpp files.

BTW, the Cocos2d-x version in the book is not the same as the one i use, I have checked the books website and found this from the author: [the Authors comment on the releases for the tutorial(s)](http://rengelbert.com/blog/cocos2d-x-book-update/)

This is my first try with non-Objective-C & Cocos2d-x.

The GameLayer.h:

```
#ifndef __GAMELAYER_H__
#define __GAMELAYER_H__

#define GOAL_WIDTH 400

#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "GameSprite.h"

using namespace cocos2d;

class GameLayer : public cocos2d::CCLayer {

GameSprite  *_player1;
GameSprite  *_player2;
GameSprite  *_ball;

CCArray     *_players;
CCLabelTTF  *_player1ScoreLabel;
CCLabelTTF  *_player2ScoreLabel;

CCSize      _screenSize;

int _player1Score;
int _player2Score;

void playerScore (int player);

public:

~GameLayer();

virtual bool init();

static CCScene *scene();

CREATE_FUNC(GameLayer);

virtual void ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchesMoved(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* event);
virtual void ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* pTouches, CCEvent* event);

void update (float dt);

};

#endif // __GAMELAYER_H__
```

The messages:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-websockets'
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "GameLayer::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
  vtable for GameLayer in GameLayer.o
  "GameLayer::ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
  vtable for GameLayer in GameLayer.o
  "GameLayer::ccTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
  vtable for GameLayer in GameLayer.o
  "GameLayer::update(float)", referenced from:
  vtable for GameLayer in GameLayer.o
  "non-virtual thunk to GameLayer::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
  vtable for GameLayer in GameLayer.o
  "non-virtual thunk to GameLayer::ccTouchesEnded(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
  vtable for GameLayer in GameLayer.o
  "non-virtual thunk to GameLayer::ccTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCSet*, cocos2d::CCEvent*)", referenced from:
  vtable for GameLayer in GameLayer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't implement these functions in your GameLayer.ccp. Following the tutorial it will teach you how to implement them.